# Using Terrestrial Time in PyEphem

Tags: python, astronomy, pyephem

Is there a way to make PyEphem give times in Dynamical Time (Terrestrial Time), without using `delta_t()` every time?

According to documentations, PyEphem uses Ephemeris Time. So isn't there a way to just 'switch off' the conversion to UTC?

Answer (score 1):

Alas — I am not aware of any settings in the `libastro` library, the PyEphem is based on, that would allow the use of alternative time scales.

Comment: Doesn't PyEphem use Terrestrial Time internally to do all the calculations?

Comment: Yes — internally, where it cannot be accessed or seen. But I am not aware that it ever exposes TT to the caller?